# Turning a baseball bat around its center not around the side you hold it: is it possible?

Tags: centripetal-force

Is this move possible? If yes, how?

[image]

Comment: You can see what's going on in this slow-motion video of tricks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JF-VZE2moc

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be possible?

Comment: If his arms were only ever moving in the same direction - in one swinging motion - it would be impossible, I think. But in the middle of his swing (from left to right) he pushes the handle of the bat from right to left.

Comment: Thanks @innisfree for the link and the explanation! The slow motion really shows the little move he makes just before making the bat swing! Amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what's going on in this [slow-motion video of tricks by Josh Womack](http://youtube.com/watch?v=4JF-VZE2moc).

If his arms were only ever moving in the same direction - in one swinging motion - it would be impossible, I think. But in the middle of his swing (from left to right) he pushes the handle of the bat from right to left.